# connecting arduino uno r3 and wifi esp8266 and sending a "1" to another wifi board when button is pressed

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

the problem is that
`if (msg.equals("Pressed")){ wasPressed = 1; }`
is not running when button is pressed.  I can see the word "Pressed" getting sent in between the two board.  But I feel like maybe either String msg = newPort.readStringUntil('\r'); is not working or msg is not exactly formatted as "Pressed"

code for wifi:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "ESPAsyncWebSrv.h"
 
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial newPort (D1,D2);
String msg;
// Set your access point network credentials
const char* ssid = "my wifi";
const char* password = "1234512345";
 
// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);
 
String greeting() {
  return String("Welcome to Dawei's WiFi");
  // return msg;
  //return String(1.8 * bme.readTemperature() + 32);
}

int wasPressed = 0;


String status() {
  if (wasPressed){
    return String("1");
  } else {
    return String("0");
  }
}
 
 
void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);
  newPort.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  
  // Setting the ESP as an access point
  Serial.print("Setting AP (Access Point)…");
  // Remove the password parameter, if you want the AP (Access Point) to be open
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
 
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  IPAddress staticIP(192, 168, 4, 1);
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);
  delay(3000);
 
  // server.on("/welcome", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  //   request->send_P(200, "text/plain", greeting().c_str());
  // });

  server.on("/status", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", status().c_str());
  });
 
  
  
  // Start server
  server.begin();
}
 
 
 
void loop(){
  String msg = newPort.readStringUntil('\r');
  //Serial.print("Received message: ");
  Serial.println(msg);
    if (msg.equals("Pressed")){
      wasPressed = 1;
    }
  // delay(1000);
  // yield();
}
```

code for arduino:
//

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
int counter = 0;

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(13)==LOW){
    Serial.println("Pressed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not Pressed");
  }  
  delay(1000);
}
```

I am just expecting to see a "1" when the buttonm is pressed, but that if condition is giving me trouble and it never run that block of code.  the other wifi board is just constantly getting a "0"
the serial shows
Received message:
Not Pressed
Received message:
Pressed

Maybe msg is blank, because I expected to see
Received message: Not Pressed
Not Pressed

Comment: only do readStringUntil if `newPort.available()`